# How to set the position of the end bracket in CLion

Tags: c++, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'd like to write code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    // something
}
```

But, in CLion, the following code is generated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    // something
    }
```

I'd like CLion to generate code like the first example.
How can I set the position of the end bracket?

Comment: what's the difference? No problem with bracket position.

Comment: There are approximately four thousand formatting options in CLion. Have you looked through them?

Comment: Of course. CLion1.2 has a new feature called "Adjust code style settings", which shows code style options for selected sentences and I tried all options which the feature showed but I couldn't find settings for this. And IntelliJ IDEA generates code for Java like the first example. So, I suspect it's kind of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the [braces placement style](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/code-style-c-c.html#d17538e411) to "Next line" instead of "Next line shifted".

Comment: Thank you for making a comment, but the solution doesn't work for me. I didn't use "Next line shifted", and I tried all options for the "braces placement style", however any options aren't helpful for this question. Thank you for giving me an advice!